# can.js validate method not working

Tags: canjs

Could anybody help me calling a validation function in can.js?
I'm adding can.jquery.js and can.map.validations.js
and then create such a small example:

```
var mymap = can.Map.extend({
    init: function () {
      this.validatePresenceOf('myfield'); // this line reports an error
    }
});
```

when loading page with this script, I get an error in browser:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Actually any this.validate* function does not work

After some research I notice that when I put this code under

```
$(document).ready{}
```

it works, but if I put it into .js file and load via  tag - browser reports an error.

And I'm not going to write all of my js code in the page itself

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802959/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setup-of-undefined-in-canjs) it tells pretty clearly(helped me last time) that you have to use $document.ready() or else it wont work, so try making a new file.js, have $document.ready() contain all your todo-code, and link it up, I hope I am helpful in this regard, if not then bug me up I wont mind at all :) ..

Comment: this is clear, but what is not clear to me - is why?? I don't find anything in can.js source code that would indicate a need of using document.ready vs simple js execution..

Comment: then it is better that you use simple js execution

Answer (score -1):

Commenting it late but anyway - it didn't work for me in either case so I just took the sample from http://jsbin.com/jofeq/5/edit?html,js,output - and copied it to my code. Surprisingly it worked after copying - not sure what was wrong on my side.

In that example it looks like this:

```
var Person = can.Map({
init: function () {
    this.validatePresenceOf('firstName');
    this.validatePresenceOf('lastName');
}
}, {});
```

and it works without document.ready tricks or anything else - just included into `body` tag

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.